# Installing Ember Data - confused by bower options

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, bower, ember-cli

These are the options that I get when running `bower install ember-data --save`:

```
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#0.0.14
bower validate      0.0.14 against git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#*
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.0.1
bower validate      1.0.1 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#~1.0.0
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.11.3
bower validate      1.11.3 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#>= 1.8.1 < 2.0.0
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.11.3
bower validate      1.11.3 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#>=1.4 <2
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.11.3
bower validate      1.11.3 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#> 1.5.0-beta.3
bower cached        git://github.com/components/handlebars.js.git#1.3.0
bower validate      1.3.0 against git://github.com/components/handlebars.js.git#>= 1.0.0 < 2.0

Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
    1) ember#~1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and is required by ember-data#0.0.14 
    2) ember#1.11.1 which resolved to 1.11.1 and is required by live 
    3) ember#>= 1.8.1 < 2.0.0 which resolved to 1.11.3 and is required by ember-data#1.0.0-beta.16.1 
    4) ember#>=1.4 <2 which resolved to 1.11.3 and is required by ember-cli-shims#0.0.3 
    5) ember#> 1.5.0-beta.3 which resolved to 1.11.3 and is required by ember-resolver#0.1.15Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

How do I know which is the right one for my current setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that  you're trying to install a **very** old version of Ember-Data (like 2+ years old). It's simply not compatible with the latest versions of Ember. (I'm surprised it's compatible with 1.0.0.) The latest version in bower (as of writing this) is `1.0.0-beta.16.1`. I would try installing that version instead.

If your app is written for Ember-Data 0.14, you're going to want to upgrade ASAP. It's probably not going to be simple, as there have been a LOT of changes since then, but 0.14 is simply too old and out-of-date to really be useful at this point in time. Certainly too old to be used with Ember CLI.